# Change automatically created name appearing in square brackets when citing

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm using bibtex and I'm facing a problem with the automatically created name which appears in square brackets when citing (e.g. "... not my idea [xyz17]").

My bib entry has 4 authors (see code below), and all four have a double name!
This creates the name [EBCBGMZM11] (how is this thing called? bibtex tag?) which does not look very good because it is very long.
Is there a way to override this, i.e. by specifying the name directly (e.g. [EBCB+11] would be ok)?

```
@article{boquera2011,
    title={{Improving offline handwritten text recognition with hybrid HMM/ANN models}},
    author={Espana-Boquera, S. and Castro-Bleda, M. and Gorbe-Moya, J. and Zamora-Martinez, F.},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence},
    volume={33},
    number={4},
    pages={767--779},
    year={2011},
    publisher={IEEEs}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you are using the `alpha` bibliography style; for sure, the `alpha` bibliography style produces the citation call-out label `EBCBGMZM11` for the entry you provided in your posting.

I suggest you enclose the two-part surnames in curly braces. That way, BibTeX will produce `ECGZ11` as the citation call-out label -- much more manageable, right?

Incidentally, the sample bib entry you provided contains several errors. Most importantly, only two of the four two-part surnames are hyphenated; the other two are separated by a space character. Also, don't forget to track down which characters are accented -- it's a very important part of Spanish surnames and given names. Finally, since the `alpha` bibliography style does *not* truncate given names, you should probably make an effort to provide the full forms of the given names, not just "S", "M", etc.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{boquera2011a,
    title  = {Improving offline handwritten text 
              recognition with hybrid {HMM/ANN} models},
    author = {Espa{\~n}a Boquera, Salvador and 
              Castro Bleda, Mar{\'i}a Jos{\'e} and 
              Gorbe-Moya, Jorge and 
              Zamora-Mart{\'i}nez, Francisco},
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis 
               and Machine Intelligence},
    volume  = {33},
    number  = {4},
    pages   = {767--779},
    year    = {2011},
    publisher={IEEEs},
}
@article{boquera2011b,
    title  = {Improving offline handwritten text 
              recognition with hybrid {HMM/ANN} models},
    author = {{Espa{\~n}a Boquera}, Salvador and 
              {Castro Bleda}, Mar{\'i}a Jos{\'e} and 
              {Gorbe-Moya}, Jorge and 
              {Zamora-Mart{\'i}nez}, Francisco},
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis 
               and Machine Intelligence},
    volume  = {33},
    number  = {4},
    pages   = {767--779},
    year    = {2011},
    publisher={IEEEs},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\hyphenation{off-line}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{boquera2011a}, \cite{boquera2011b}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that solved it - thank you very much!

Comment: @Harry - You're most welcome!