# Cite Website where the author is an institution - last name problem

Tags: biblatex

I need to cite the curriculum from the website of the french education ministry. The problem is that when I write the name "ministère de l'éducation nationale" in the author field, latex thinks that nationale is the last name and places it in front. Is there a way to fix this?

```
    \documentclass[titlepage,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}


@online{cm2,
  author = {Ministère de l'éducation national},
  title = {Programme et horaires à l'école primaire cycle 3 - Bulletin officiel n°30},
  year = 26.7.2018,
  url = {http://cache.media.education.gouv.fr/file/30/05/0/ensel169_annexe2V2_986050.pdf},
  urldate = {2019-04-03}
}

\end{filecontents}



\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}


\addbibresource{ref.bib}



\usepackage{setspace}



\begin{document}


That is a citation \footcite[Cf.]{cm2}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use double brackets (`author = {{Ministère de l'éducation national}}`), see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403751/change-automatically-created-name-appearing-in-square-brackets-when-citing.

Comment: You need double braces for so-called corporate authors `author = {{Ministère de l'éducation national}},` See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864. The `year` field can only contain a year, if you want to give a full date, you need to use the `date` field and you must give the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format regardless of the desired output. `date = {2018-07-26},`.

Comment: I voted to close this question as a duplicate of our standard "corporate author" question. If for some reason adding double braces does not work (I verified that `author = {{Ministère de l'éducation national}},` in your MWE) for you, please edit your question with more details and we can reopen it.